# Varnish/Fastly - Georedirecting All Site URLs to One Page Except for the Store Locator

Tags: magento2, varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly

I am attempting to redirect all traffic from certain countries to one centralized page (fall-2023-collection) except for one other page (store-locator). I have the redirection working in the sense that all pages redirect to `fall-2023-collection`, including `store-locator`. I have tried multiple conditional combinations with if/elseif/else but I have not had any luck getting the `store-locator` to load as expected.

This is what I have for the `recv` event;

```
if (req.http.host ~ "site\.url" && req.url != "/fall-2023-collection" && req.url != "/store-locator"  && req.url !~ "\.(jpe?g|gif|png|webp|css|js|json|svg|woff|woff2|html|)$" && table.lookup(georedirect, client.geo.country_code)) {
  error 618 "redirect";
}
elseif (req.http.host ~ "site\.url" && req.url == "/store-locator" && table.lookup(georedirect, client.geo.country_code)) {
  error 617 "redirect_loc";
}
else {
  return (pass);
}
```

And this is what I have for the `error` event;

```
if (obj.status == 618 && obj.response == "redirect") {
  set obj.status = 308;
  set obj.http.Location = "https://" + req.http.host + "/fall-2023-collection";
  return (deliver);
}

if (obj.status == 617 && obj.response == "redirect_loc") {
  set obj.status = 308;
  set obj.http.Location = "https://" + req.http.host + "/store-locator";
  return (deliver);
}
```

`georedirect` is just a table with the two letter country codes so it's not really relevant. That part works as expected. I verified that using a VPN so that's not where I'm having my main issue.

Answer (score 0):

A great tool to help you debug issues like this is Fastly Fiddle:
https://fiddle.fastly.dev/

I used it to produce a working example:
https://fiddle.fastly.dev/fiddle/be5f942f

In the linked fiddle I issue five requests:

1. `/anything/the-intended-destination?beep=boop`
2. `/anything/dont-redirect-this-either?=fizz=buzz`
3. `/anything/foo`
4. `/anything/bar`
5. `/anything/baz`

The first request should just reach its destination.

The second request should just reach its destination.

The third, fourth and fifth requests should be redirected to `/anything/the-intended-destination`.

I didn't implement the table lookup as you mentioned this was working for you, and so the main change I made was a switch from `req.url` to `req.url.path` as the latter doesn't include query string params.

Any query string params on the incoming request would cause your check (which used `req.url`) to fail.

If you have any future questions or issues regarding Fastly, feel free to reach out to any of the following...

- support@fastly.com (the Fastly support team are always happy to help)
- https://community.fastly.com/ (the official Fastly forums)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/fastly/ (the official Fastly subreddit)
- Stack Overflow and tagging #fastly

> **NOTE:** The list above is in descending order of importance as far as official Fastly support (i.e. you'll get the least amount of eyes/feedback when posting to Stack Overflow). So I recommend asking questions either in the official community forum, or better still, emailing Fastly Support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that gives me more to work with!